# apache configuration

Tags: apache

I'm not good at English.

I use Ubuntu10.04(ja).

I installed pukiwiki(wiki) in /var/www/mypukiwiki. I want to access this page like "http://XX.XX.XX.XX" and redirect "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki" and "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki/" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX". So, I modified my default configuration file below.

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypukiwiki
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /pukiwiki/(.*) /$1 [R]
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mypukiwiki>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            #AllowOverride None
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

But, Apache redirect only "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki/" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX".
Apache cannot redirect "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki/" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX".

Why? I want to know correct configuration.

Would you help me?

Comment: *Apache redirect only "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki/" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX". Apache cannot redirect "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki/" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX".* Aren't these 2 things the same?

Comment: Oh,sorry...I mistyped. Apache cannot redirect "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/pukiwiki" to "http://XX.XX.XX.XX".

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
RewriteRule /pukiwiki/(.*) /$1 [R]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^/pukiwiki/?(.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

The **^** in the beginning of the match is to ensure you're matching from the beginning of the path, and not match against something like "/foo/bar/pukiwiki", the **?** after the slash indicates that it's optional.